# react-native (js) : generalise a function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have two functions which I would like to condense into one (with another argument). They are called like so:

```
<ListView
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource_proj}
    renderRow={this.renderProjRow.bind(this)}/>
<ListView
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource_map}
    renderRow={this.renderMapRow.bind(this)}/>
```

And the functions are:

```
renderProjRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID) {
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.rowProjPressed(rowData.project_name)}
            underlayColor='#dddddd'>
            <View>
                <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
                    <Image source={{uri: 'Letter-' + rowData.project_name.substr(0,1).toUpperCase()}} 
                        style={styles.thumb}/>
                    <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.title}
                            numberOfLines={1}>{rowData.project_name}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View Style={styles.separator}/>
            </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    );
}

renderMapRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID) {
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.rowMapPressed(rowData)}
            underlayColor='#dddddd'>
            <View>
                <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
                    <Image source={{uri: 'Letter-' + rowData.map_name.substr(0,1).toUpperCase()}} 
                        style={styles.thumb}/>
                    <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.title}
                            numberOfLines={1}>{rowData.map_name}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View Style={styles.separator}/>
            </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        );
}
```

I would like to just have one function: `renderRow`, which takes `rowData.project_name` if the data-source is `dataSource_proj` and `rowData.map_name` if the data-source is `dataSource_map`.

However, aside from using eval ... I'm not sure how to implement this in a proper way.

Comment: Not sure why you need evai. Can't you do `rowData[type]` ?

Comment: If  your data can have same properties names, then it would be easier to use same function, otherwise it seems unnecessarily complex.